# React Cart Not Rendering After Placing Order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I'm currently working on a React application with a shopping cart feature. The issue I'm facing is that after placing an order, the cart is not re-rendering as expected. The order placement seems to be successful, but the cart UI is not updating.

Cart.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Placeorder from './Placeorder';

function Cart() {
  const [cartItemsWithDetails, setCartItemsWithDetails] = useState([]);
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [orderPlaced, setOrderPlaced] = useState(false);
  const fetchCart = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/cart/get-cart', {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include',
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    return data.cart;
  };
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProductDetails = async () => {
      const cartItemsData = await fetchCart();
  
      if (!cartItemsData || cartItemsData.length === 0) {
        return;
      }
  
      const productDetailsPromises = cartItemsData.map(async (item) => {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/v1/products/get/${item.productId}`, {
          method: 'GET',
        });
        const productDetails = await response.json();
        return { ...item, productDetails };
      });
  
      const productsWithDetails = await Promise.all(productDetailsPromises);
      setCartItemsWithDetails(productsWithDetails);
    };
  
    fetchProductDetails();
    if (orderPlaced) {
      setOrderPlaced(false); // Reset the state after fetching
    }
  }, [orderPlaced]); // Add orderPlaced as a dependency here
  

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto p-4 mt-8">
      <div className="max-w-2xl mx-auto bg-white p-6 rounded-md shadow-md">
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Shopping Cart</h2>

        {cartItemsWithDetails.length === 0 ? (
          <p>Your cart is empty.</p>
        ) : (
          <div>
            {cartItemsWithDetails.map((item) => (
              <div key={item.productId} className="mb-4 border-b border-gray-300 pb-4">
                <p className="text-gray-600 mb-2">{`Product: ${item.productDetails.product.name}`}</p>
                <p className="text-gray-600 mb-2">{`Price: $${item.productDetails.product.price}`}</p>
                <p className="text-gray-600 mb-2">{`Quantity: ${item.quantity}`}</p>
              </div>
            ))}

            <div className="mt-4">
              <button onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(true)} className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                Proceed to Checkout
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}

        {modalIsOpen && (
          <Placeorder
            products={cartItemsWithDetails.map((item) => ({
              product: item.productId,
              quantity: item.quantity,
            }))}
            isOpen={modalIsOpen}
            onRequestClose={()=>{
              setModalIsOpen(false);
  setOrderPlaced(true)
            }}
            
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Cart;
```

Placeorder.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Placeorder({products, isOpen, onRequestClose }) {
    const [shippingInfo, setShippingInfo] = useState({
        address: '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        country: '',
        pinCode: 123456,
        phoneNo: 1234567890,
    });

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setShippingInfo((prevShippingInfo) => ({
            ...prevShippingInfo,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    };

    const handleSaveShippingInfo = async () => {
        try {
          console.log('Shipping Info:', shippingInfo);
          console.log(products);
      
          const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/orders/place-order', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ shippingInfo, products }),
          });
      
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
          }
      
          const data = await response.json();
          console.log(data);
      
          // Close the modal after saving shipping info
          onRequestClose()
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error:', error.message);
        }
      };
      

    return (
        <div className={`fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto ${isOpen ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}`} aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
            <div className="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
                <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                <span className="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>
                <div className="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full">
                    <div className="bg-white p-8">
                        <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-4">Enter Shipping Information</h1>

                        <label htmlFor="address" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" id="address" name="address" className="w-full px-3 py-2 mb-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Enter address" value={shippingInfo.address} onChange={handleChange} required />

                        <label htmlFor="city" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">City</label>
                        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" className="w-full px-3 py-2 mb-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Enter city" value={shippingInfo.city} onChange={handleChange} required />
                        <label htmlFor="state" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">State</label>
                        <input type="text" id="state" name="state" className="w-full px-3 py-2 mb-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Enter state" value={shippingInfo.state} onChange={handleChange} required />
                        <label htmlFor="country" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Country</label>
                        <input type="text" id="country" name="country" className="w-full px-3 py-2 mb-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Enter country" value={shippingInfo.country} onChange={handleChange} required />
                        <label htmlFor="pinCode" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">PinCode</label>
                        <input type="number" id="pinCode" name="pinCode" className="w-full px-3 py-2 mb-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Enter pinCode" value={shippingInfo.pinCode} onChange={handleChange} required />
                        <label htmlFor="phoneNo" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Contact</label>
                        <input type='number' id="phoneNo" name="phoneNo" className="w-full px-3 py-2 mb-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Enter phoneNo" value={shippingInfo.phoneNo} onChange={handleChange} required />
                       

                        <div className="flex justify-between">
                            <button onClick={onRequestClose} className="bg-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-md text-black mr-2">Cancel</button>
                            <button onClick={handleSaveShippingInfo} className="bg-green-600 px-4 py-2 rounded-md text-white">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Placeorder;
```

When i placeorder and submit shipping details the order is placed successfully but Cart components is not re-rendering , i want it to re-render so that Carts get updated.

I have tried using setOrderPlaced with the callback form to ensure I'm working with the updated state.
I have added orderPlaced as a dependency in the useEffect to trigger a re-fetch when the order is placed